# node.js + request => response showing junk response

Tags: node.js, http, request

I am using the node.js + request for send HTTP request to URL. I required the JSON response, but I get junk character.

Here is my node.js code

```
var request = require('request');
var post_data = { UserName: "xxxxx", Password: "xxxxx" };

var post_options = {
  url: 'http://xxxxxxx.info/api/CoreUser/cognitoLogin',
  method: 'POST',
  form: post_data,
  headers: {
    'AppID': 'zNiphaJww8e4qYEwJ96g555HTAAbAXdj',
    'OAuth': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    //'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  }
};
// Set up the request
request(post_options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("200");
    console.log(response);

  }
});
```

But I received response in junk characters.

[image] 
I need result in jSON format, What is wrong in this request?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, reason is that API response send in gZip format. Here is the change we have to made here. Just enable `gzip: true` that resolve the things.

```
var request = require('request');
var post_data = { UserName: "xxxxx", Password: "xxxxx" };

var post_options = {
  url: 'http://xxxxxxx.info/api/CoreUser/cognitoLogin',
  method: 'POST',
  gzip: true,
  form: post_data,
  headers: {
    'AppID': 'zNiphaJww8e4qYEwJ96g555HTAAbAXdj',
    'OAuth': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    //'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  }
};
// Set up the request
request(post_options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("200");
    console.log(response);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `{ json: true }` in request call

```
request(post_options, { json: true }, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("200");
    console.log(response);

  }
});
```